# RSelenium in the cloud

Tags: r, google-colaboratory, kaggle, rselenium

I want to run RSelenium ([CRAN web site](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html)) in a (free) cloud. I have a subscription to RStudio Cloud, but apparently is not possible to open a web browser with this service provider, given that RStudio Cloud doesn't provide those permissions.

Other alternatives I have are Google Colab and Kaggle notebooks. Is it possible to run RSelenium in Colab or Kaggle notebooks? How?

Comment: The problem in your case is not RSelenium its Selenium itself. You can run Selenium with headless webdrivers (I think at least Chrome and Firefox have them), but you still need (the rights) to install the drivers on the machine you're running on. I strongly doubt that its possible to install the drivers in RStudio Cloud, Google Colab or Kaggle. 
Your own VM in the cloud would be a different story.

Comment: Is possible to install the chrome driver with `!apt install chromium-chromedriver` in google colab. Running selenium with python is indeed posible in colab, but I would like to do it in R. I just don't know how the programming and driver settings will change within an R instance (I'm more of a data scientist than a programmer, so this is kind of new to me).